# Android Gps location

Tags: android

I enabled the GPS in my device but I am not getting the loaction:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
{
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(location!=null)
    {
        showCurrentAddress(location);
    }
}
```

But here I am gettin location is null and I added the following permissions to my code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Try this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655

For Discuss Get GPs Location

Comment: Try this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655

Answer (score 1):

`lm.getLastKnownLocation` can return `null` because that is a getter for the last known location.

Try using `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationListener)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this tutorial for GPS location , i am also using this code for getting latitude and longitude[Using GPS to get current location – Android tutorial](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)  check this on your device not on emulator first time just wait for few seconds..